# Smsgateway.me API - REST Mod disabled on V4

Tags: android, rest, api, sms, gateway

I've updated everything for their new API v4 and also the new Android application (the old one was removed from the Play Store).

Now I'm having a problem with the messages in application running android 5.0, I've to press "Check Server Now" everytime to check for new messages (which are sent to API correctly but gets the status Pending until I press in the app manually).

Someone tolds us to install the previous version of the .apk to solve this issue but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is correct since May 12 I did need to update my php version it took a while but when I finally get it my phone did not need to download the app again now I see that play on my favor, I did use the app with no problems, I also saw that the sending process was not even aligned with the every minute I configure on my old samsung.

Today sadly 9/2/2018 my cell stop to work better said the app claimed for internet to be able to connect, of course I had WiFi and 4G but looks like something happened a 6 am pacific time.

I was expecting it was a problem with server so I wait patiently until 2 PM, and I asked my son to see the app on his phone Samsung J7 and the app was asking for user and password

I knew that the J7 was not able to configure the asking time to server looking for pending sms's but I thought will be enough for today sending messages every 5 minutes thinking was the default time. But did not work unless we click the manual form in the app or at least having the app on the screen swivel and will update sending sms's as mentioned leaving the status on pending and some times sent.

I did something stupid delete my old version of the app from my old samsung and guess what, I could not download the new version for incompatibility with my phone, I still not sure if my old version will start to work later on the day or tomorrow, but certainly I lost the opportunity to know.

I used https://apkpure.com/es/sms-gateway-api/networked.solutions.sms.gateway.api go get the older version an installed again on my SGH-M919V Samsung Android 4.4.2 not compatible anymore so the option of configure the refresh is not there any more, J7 was not able to do that,

Sep 3 2018 team upload new version since the notification process to send the sms did not work, the new version suppose to ask server every 2 min not working on my J7 Samsung. so at this point I have to send the messages clicking manually to search on the server for sms pending to send.

Comment: I finnaly had an answer from the dev ! Houra! 
They said they are using google FCM to send notifications to the device whenever there is a message to send.
This decision was made since we have the app on 7,500+ devices it causes a large load on the server.
 
However FCM seems to sometime fail depending on which country you are in / version of android you have installed.

They just released an update on september 3th to fix this issue in which if FCM fails the app will automatically check the server every 2 minutes.

Comment: Unfortunately this update did not solve the problem for me (tested on two devices on Android 6 with the new APK)

Comment: Mexico Samsung J7 Android 6.0.1 not working either with smsgateway.me version 4.1.1 Sep 3rd. Samsung SGH-M919V I installed SMS Gateway API_v3.1_apkpure.com.apk (2.0 MB) but behave as sep 2nd so the problems is the server, This cell phone work great from mid June until Sep 2 This phone with the SMSGateway.me 3.1 version was able to configure frequency of asking server for new SMS messages. I am going to cross to usa and see if something us different. Thanks Kyler

Comment: I just came back from USA and both phones using ATT on USA did not refresh sending sms automatically so the problem is there, click manually to send the sms messages recorded in the server. The Samsung SGH-M919V did not open the app as mentioned before so v3.1 is gone!

Comment: Sepehr, the dev, just sent an email to say that the issue is now fixed. 
To resolve the issue:
Open the app and press the "Check Server Now" button
After that, it should check the server automatically whenever you have a pending message.